# Different results when using regular variable assignment and mass variable assignment

Tags: ruby

Translated a function that uses mass variable assignment to a function that uses regular variable assignment

```
# mass assignment
def fibo_finder n
    a, b = 0, 1
    n.times { a, b = b, a + b }
    a
end

# regular assignment
def fibo_finder2 n
    a = 0
    b = 1
    n.times do
        a = b
        b = a + b
    end

    return a
end

puts "Must be: 3. fibo_finder: #{fibo_finder(4)} fibo_finder2: #{fibo_finder2(4)}"
puts "Must be: 13. fibo_finder: #{fibo_finder(7)} fibo_finder2: #{fibo_finder2(7)}"
puts "Must be: 55. fibo_finder: #{fibo_finder(10)} fibo_finder2: #{fibo_finder2(10)}"
```

Running the code results to:

> Must be: 3. fibo_finder: 3 fibo_finder2: 8
>
> Must be: 13. fibo_finder: 13 fibo_finder2: 64
>
> Must be: 55. fibo_finder: 55 fibo_finder2: 512

At first glance, the two functions look equivalent aside from how the variables were assigned. But the results show otherwise.

Is Ruby doing something special when variables are assigned using mass assignment?

I'm using [repl](https://repl.it/BEVW) to run the code

Comment: `a = b` followed by `b = a + b` is just `b = b + b`. `a, b = b, a + b` does not change `a` before evaluating `a + b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two assignments are not equivalent.

In the parallel assignment:

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

The right hand side are evaluated, collected an an array, and then the left hand side gets the value from this array. It's equivalent to:

```
arr = [b, a + b]
a, b = arr
```

Note that in `b` gets the value of `a + b` with the original value of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In your mass assignment example:

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

the assignments are carried out in parallel - both right-hand expressions are evaluated and then the two results are assigned to the left hand side.

In your second example:

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

`a` is set to `b` and *then* `b` is set to `a + b` (or, `b + b` because `a` is now equal to `b`)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose:

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

Then with parallel assignment,

```
a,b = b,a #=> [2, 1] 
a         #=> 2 
b         #=> 1
```

By contrast:

```
a = 1
b = 2

a = b     #=> 2 
b = a     #=> 2 
a         #=> 2
b         #=> 2
```

Parallel assignment is often used for swapping values of variables, to avoid the need to create a temporary variable. If it worked as in my second example you couldn't use it for that.